# Need to Ping from one process to another

Tags: process, ping

I have two process P1 and P2. I want to ping from P1 to P2 to tell P2
that it is alive and working. How do I do that?

Comment: What kind of processes? What language are they written in? Are they on the same machine?

Comment: Depending on your language, OS, and definition of "ping", a simple kill 0 might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the same machine (assuming there is a file system), you could use a "heart beat file". Have P1 update the file with the current time-stamp periodically, and P2 can check if that gets too old. You can also write the P1 process id in there, and P2 can check if that pid is still alive.

Comment: Hi Thilo,
 Thank you very much for your response. I am not aware of heart beat file. Any info or link to understand that will be much appreciated.

Comment: It is just a small text file in a well-known location that your process updates while it is running.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a network socket listener on P2 that P1 connects to periodically.  You'll need to specify the language you're using for a more specific code example.

As Thilo mentioned below, since they are on the same system you could use a simple file as the "I'm alive" message.  Here's an example:

- Have "P1" update the file with the current time every few seconds.  Here is a shell example (sorry, I don't do C++ well):

```
     rm /tmp/P1.heartbeat
     date +%s > /tmp/P1.heartbeat
```

- P2 then opens-reads-closes the file.  It then compares it to the current time and takes the appropriate action if the time in the file is "too old".

  - Just make sure your P2 system closes the file after each read to make sure it re-reads the new file.

```
     X=`cat /tmp/P1.heartbeat`
     NOW=`date +%s`
     DIFF=$(( $NOW - $X))
     if [ $DIFF -gt 60 ] ; then
       echo P1 died $DIFF seconds ago.
     fi
```

Comment: I am using C++. Process will run on same machine.

Comment: What I mean by ping here is Process P1 has to repeatedly tell proces P2 that it is alive. If it stops pinging then P2 will kill p1.